# Plot histogram of oriented gradients (HOG) over an image in R

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to implement a procedure similar to that of MatLab whereby HOG features are extracted from an image and then plotted over either the original image, or simply standalone to estimate the shape/template of the image (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html), and below). HOG feature extraction can be easily done in R via the OpenImageR's `HOG()` function, but I cannot figure out a way to recreate the plot in R. Preferably, there would be a way to overlay the features extracted onto an image via `ggplot` and `raster`.

HOG features overlaid on image

[image: HOG features overlaid on image]

HOG features plotted by itself
[image: HOG features plotted by itself]

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal example from R and `OpenImageR`

```
library(OpenImageR)
path = system.file("tmp_images", "1.png", package = "OpenImageR")
image = rgb_2gray(readImage(path))
image=image*255 # Convert to gray values
hog = HOG(image, cells = 9, orientations = 4)
```

Essentially, I load an image and extract the HOG features by slicing the 32x32 image 4 (4*4) times, and collecting 4 orientations per slice block resulting in a long unidimensional vector of 64 values (4*4 slices * 4 orientations). The trouble I am having is moving from HOG features to visualization like in the examples provided.

Comment: how far have you gotten with `OpenImageR`'s `HOG` function?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include the code you've already written (such as the code to run `HOG()`).

Comment: I've edited my question to provide some addition information, and a reproducible example.

Comment: @DrPineapple, the HOG function ports a C++ function which does not support plotting of the HOG features. However, if you have access to python from your operating system then you can use the [reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate) package to plot the HOG features as I described in one of my [blog posts](http://mlampros.github.io/2017/04/13/fuzzywuzzyR_package/).